# Including the type name in a variable name

Tags: c#, mvvm, variables, code-formatting

Abstract: Is it acceptable to include the type name in the variable name?

My scenario:

I am working with C# MVVM, and I have a lot of `ICommand` properties in my ViewModel, named various things like `GetSomething`, `DoSomething`, `WriteSomething`, etc. The "rule" for ordering members in C# is alphabetically, so I have my commands strewn throughout the file. Even if I sort them manually, it can be difficult to remember that `GetSomething` is a `ICommand`, especially when there are two methods for each command (the `void` execute and the `bool` can execute) and a `MenuItem` the command is bound to (the menu is generated dynamically in code-behind).

I would like to name my commands `CommandGetSomething`, in which case I could then have `ExecuteGetSomething`, `CanExecuteGetSomething`, and `MenuItemGetSomething` so that all of the parts for the different commands are at least alphabetically next to each other (`ExecuteDoSomething` would be next to `ExecuteGetSomething` would be next to `ExecuteWriteSomething`).

Am I even trying to solve the right problem here? The ViewModel has about thirty different commands, plus other stuff, so it is important that the file is ordered logically. I use ReSharper to sort the contents, and while I wish that I could sort by type name directly, the closest I can get is alphabetically (which is default).

Comment: To figure out what `Execute()` and `CanExecute()` are actually executing, *look at the concrete type that is being instantiated.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typically referred to as "Hungarian Notation", and is overwhelmingly frowned upon by every source I've ever seen.

The problem is, what happens if you change the underlying type down the road? Now you're forced to either rename all your associated variables, or deal with a potentially misleading name.

Sure, with a good IDE you can easily do a bulk rename if need-be, but at the same time, if you have an IDE capable enough to pull this off, it'll likely also be able to automatically infer the type, and maybe even display the associated documentation.

Let the language and IDE deal with typing. Encoding that information into your names just opens up the potential for mistakes down the road when things inevitably change.

Comment: There's only one remaining useful case, and that is UI, even if it's just prefixing all of your control names with `ux`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh, honestly, I haven't done near enough UI stuff to know anything about that. Look up my submitted code review for a Game of Life clone. It's pretty sad lol.

Comment: More precisely, this is the *bad kind* of Hungarian, the one which *duplicates* information. (Unlike the "slightly less bad kind", which encodes *additional* information in the name.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just realized, wouldn't it more appropriate to just put UI related stuff in its own namespace?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: you're referring to systems v. apps Hungarian, correct?

Comment: @outis: Yes. I always forget which is which, though. The reason I call it "slightly less bad", is because I believe that if the information is important enough to be encoded in the name, then it is also important enough to be encoded in the type system (or something similar, such as annotations, attributes, etc.) so that it can be checked by the machine. If, OTOH, it isn't important enough to be machine-checked, then it probably isn't important enough to be encoded *at all*. So, one is bad because it is redundant, the other is bad, because the information should be machine-checked instead.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: it's definitely less useful the stronger the type system is and with static typing, but more useful with weaker & dynamically typed languages (basically taking the place of static, strong typing with these, at the programmer, rather than language, level). Go Haskell!

Answer (score 0):

I've always put the name of the interface or class that I am implementing/inheriting at the end.

I believe it should be `GetSomethingCommand`.  Of course if your implementing multiple interfaces then the convention doesn't really work, so use with judgement.

I took this from MSDN:

> The second part of the derived class's name should be the name of the
>   base class. For example, ApplicationException is an appropriate name
>   for a class derived from a class named Exception, because
>   ApplicationException is a kind of Exception. Use reasonable judgment
>   in applying this rule. For example, Button is an appropriate name for
>   a class derived from Control. Although a button is a kind of control,
>   making Control a part of the class name would lengthen the name
>   unnecessarily.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xhs4564(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This isn't what the question is really about.  The Exception suffix is well-established and well-known, and so are the conventions that the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

There are several interesting references that do recommend not to encode types within variable names:

- [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin)'s "*Clean Code*" recommends to [avoid encodings (type, scope) in names](http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83), because they are a mental burden and not needed anymore with modern IDE and tools.
- Stroustrup, Sutter and al. also discourage these types of conventions in "C++ core guidelines" because they [hinder evolution of code](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rl-name-type).

All the arguments put forward about the subject are rather language neutral and should be applicable to C# as well.

But as everythig related to style and conventions, this recommendation shall not become a dogma.  R.C.Martin also recommends that names shall reveal intentions.  In your case you're in a grey zone:  it's not recommended to encode the type `Command` as prefix. However starting a variable with `Command` also reveals the intentions about the variable.